# azure java using ACS filter- how to?

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-java-sdk

i cant figure out how to use/configure the azure ACS for use in my azure hosted jetty webapp.

I have read the [azure acs with eclipse plugin](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-java-authenticate-users-access-control-eclipse/)  but i am still clueless as i am not using the eclipse ACSfilter plugin.

is there a simple 'how to' on configuring the ACS filter for a web app without using the eclipse plugin?

i am expecting to swap out my currently AuthenticationFilter with an ACSFilter. is it that simple?

thanks

-lp

Answer (score 1):

There is a vedio "[How to use Azure Access Control for Single Sign-On](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/OneCode/How-to-use-Azure-Access-Control-for-Single-Sign-On)" on Channel 9 that can help you understanding the doc [How to Authenticate Web Users with Azure Access Control Service Using Eclipse](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-java-authenticate-users-access-control-eclipse/).

The plugin `Azure Toolkit for Eclipse` provides templates and functionality that allow you to easily create, develop, test, and deploy Azure applications using the Eclipse development environment. You can see the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse/ to know more details.

You can try to get started with the `Hello World` Application in Eclipse(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-creating-a-hello-world-application/).

Hope it helps. Best Regards.

Comment: pan. thanks for the link but i am not using the eclipse plugins. hence i am seeking straight forward instructions on how the ACS Filter is to be used.

Comment: @lpic I think you can try to directly the ACS jar library into your project without using the eclipse plugins after I reviewed the toturial. But I can't find the ACS maven repository. But there is a GitHub repository includes the ACS Java source code in the dir `Utils`, please see https://github.com/MSOpenTech/azure-chat-for-java.